# A quick jQuery selector question

Tags: jquery

Sorry, I'm just so selector stupid sometimes... How do I tell jQuery to give me all elements of type TABLE that have a class of "rctable"? e.g.

```
<table class="rctable" ..../>
```

Comment: Here is a good description of selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ;)

Comment: let me google that for you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("table.rctable");
```